# How to disable EditText auto complete when using textEmailAddress

Tags: android

I have an edit text with `inputType` set to `textEmailAddress` and I can't stop the keyboard from showing text suggestions. I want to use this flag so that the @ sign shows up in the first set of keyboard characters but I don't want suggestions to appear because they consume a lot of space on the screen and mess up the user experience.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/common_email"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    />
```

I have tried changing `inputType` to

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
```

and to

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textEmailAddress"
```

but it doesn't work. It seems that when used, `textEmailAddress` overrides whatever the other flags do.

Is there a way to show to make the keyboard show the @ sign but not show suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to absolutely assure that a keyboard doesn't show suggestions.  Keyboards have total control over what they display, including suggestions.  Anything you send it is just a hint as to what it should do, different keyboards interpret or ignore those hints as they please.

textVisiblePassword|textEmailAddress won't work- those are both specifying a major type.  The result will be an ORing of their bits and you'll get something really weird.  textNoSuggestions is the best bet.  If that isn't working, then that keyboard either never honors no suggestions or doesn't for email fields.

As for showing the @ sign-  same deal.  Keyboards control what keys they show.  They may change slightly for different modes, but there's no way to force specific keys to show.

As a side note-  I'm not certain turning off suggestions for email is the right thing to do.  Many keyboards will add all email addresses in contacts into their dictionaries.  Many users will add their own email to the dictionary for filling in forms.  And many email addresses are combos of common words.  Depending on how good the keyboard is with email mode, being able to do autocorrect is a better experience.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me.

android:importantForAutofill="no"